# How are these 2 pieces of code different?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

Here are Two pieces of code which perform an exact same task.
This:

```
class employees:
    raise_amount=1.04
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.pay=pay
        self.email=first + '.' +last+ '@abc.com'
        self.fullname=first+' '+last

    def raised(self):
        self.raised=self.pay*self.raise_amount



em1=employees('Carey', 'Barlog', 6000)
em2=employees('Test', 'User', 3000)
em2.raised()
print(em2.raised)
```

And This:

```
class employees:
    raise_amount=1.04
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.pay=pay
        self.email=first + '.' +last+ '@abc.com'
        self.fullname=first+' '+last
        self.raised=self.pay*self.raise_amount


em1=employees('Carey', 'Barlog', 6000)
em2=employees('Test', 'User', 3000)

print(em2.raised)
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between the two, and if i use one way over the other?

Comment: do you know the difference between a method and an attribute

Comment: @Poppinyoshi, no im super new to this class and oop stuff. Care to explain?

Comment: No, I can't explain OOP to you, you need to study it from a good book. I recommend SICP python

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet is problematic because you're using the same name `raised` for both the method and the instance attribute, so you'ㄠl be destroying the `raised` method and replacing it with the `raised` attribute after the first call.

That issue aside, the first code snippet sets the `raised` attribute only when `employees.raised()` is called, while the second code snippet sets the `raised` attribute when an instance is initialized. The former allows more control on when `raised` is calculated (possibly after `pay` and `raise_amount` get updated), and the latter allows the `raised` attribute to be always initialized with each instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, all you have to do is call the class and self.raised will be increased, as python runs `__init__` when an instance of the class employees is created.

But, if you want to make an instance and *then* raise their pay, let's say later on, you would use the second one as the pay-raising function is defined.